# Cannot compare Start Time and Start Date object with GETDATE() In query

Tags: sql-server

I wondered if anyone can advise me on where I may be missing something fairly obvious. I have seperate Date and Time objects unfortunately. So I have to bind the Date from one object and the Time from another and then compare them with the current datetime and display anything in the future. This is basically what I am doing incorrectly.

```
    select MyTable.Name, MyTable.Date, MyTable.StartTime from MyTable
    where CONVERT(datetime, MyTable.DateOfBooking) + CONVERT(datetime, MyTable.StartTime >= GETDATE());
```

I am an MSSQL novice. Would greatly appreciate any advise that you may have.

Comment: Syntax error? You dont have ) for the second CONVERT function.

Comment: I would also recommend that you make datetime columns have a datatype of datetime. Your code is nonSARGable because you have functions on your columns in the where clause. Also, do you know what will happen when you simply add two datetime values together? You should be using DATEADD instead of relying on behavior that might change in the future. And if you have two dates wouldn't you want to compare either or both them against getdate() instead of adding them together? If the date values are the same in both columns your results will be another value entirely.

Comment: Something more like this perhaps? Notice I aliased your table so it is a bit easier to type. select t.Name, t.Date, t.StartTime 
from MyTable t
where t.DateOfBooking >= GETDATE()
 AND t.StartTime >= GETDATE()

Comment: It's silly the way it's been done. Date in one column and time in another rather than just one object. The dates in both columns do not correspond which is Another problem. I have used CONVERT and I am reasonably happy with the results. Though I will definitely look into DATEADD as want it to be done correctly. Thanks for all advise.

Comment: I have a HUGE third party database that I have to manage where they store their dates/times like you describe above.  It's super annoying - I feel your pain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I resolved the problem

```
    select MyTable.Name, MyTable.Date, MyTable.StartTime from MyTable
    where CONVERT(datetime, CONVERT(varchar(13), MyTable.DateOfBooking, 103) + ' ' +   CONVERT(varchar(8), MyTable.StartTime, 108),103) >= CONVERT(datetime, GETDATE());
```